# How to create a snort content rule

Tags: snort

I am new into using snort and I don't know how to properly create rules.
I want someone to explain me how to create a rule for detection of a specific content. For example: I want to generate an alert when I search on Google the word 'terrorism'.

I tried to create the rule with what I've seen on Youtube or Google, as examples, but none of them works and I don't know what to try anymore. For instance, I am using Snort 2.9.9

alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:"terrorism content found"; content:"terrorism"; nocase; sid:1000000;)

I don't have any errors from the local.rules file, but I got the line 'include $RULE_PATH/snort.rules' commented because of some problems with PulledPork.
I expect to have an alert in the CLI, but there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is already too late but here's the answer for future reference.
The packets are probably being sent using HTTPS connection (which is why they are encrypted).
This might be a reason why there are no alerts.

Please refer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/216471/how-to-create-content-rule-in-snort/216475#216475) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

rules are ready, u just replace, *alert* with **sdrop**:

[image: snort command and rules control, fast]

```
find /home/www \( -type d -name .git -prune \) -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/subdomainA\.example\.com/subdomainB.example.com/g'
```

and you can use include in config file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

O.K
Answer is here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/u2spewfoo.8.html
Download Snort source, Make logs costume, write ur code to get log stream in control
Then Build source and run
Be successful :)

Comment: check this Article on LinkedIn:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/wie-schreibe-ich-firewall-form-base-kave-eyni

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send alert messages and some packet relevant data
from snort through a unix socket, to perform additional separate
processing of alert data.
Snort has to be built with spo_unsock.c/h output plugin is built in and
-A unsock (or its equivalent through the config file) is
used. The unix socket file should be created in /dev/snort_alert. Your
‘client’ code should act as ‘server’ listening to this unix socket.
Snort will be sending you Alertpkt structures which contain alert
message, event id. Original datagram, libpcap pkthdr, and offsets to
datalink, netlayer, and transport layer headers.

Below is an example how unix sockets could be used. If you have any
comments bug reports, and feature requests, please contact
snort-devel@lists.sourceforge.net or drop me an email to fygrave at
tigerteam dot net.

-Fyodor

[for copyright notice, see snort distribution code]

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include 
#include "snort.h"

int sockfd;

void
sig_term (int sig)
{
  printf (“Exiting!\n”);
  close (sockfd);
  unlink (UNSOCK_FILE);
  exit (1);
}

int
main (void)
{
  struct sockaddr_un snortaddr;
  struct sockaddr_un bogus;
  Alertpkt alert;
  Packet *p;
  int recv;
  socklen_t len = sizeof (struct sockaddr_un);

if ((sockfd = socket (AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
      perror (“socket”);
      exit (1);
    }

bzero (&snortaddr, sizeof (snortaddr));
  snortaddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy (snortaddr.sun_path, UNSOCK_FILE);

if (bind (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &snortaddr, sizeof (snortaddr)) < 0)
    {
      perror (“bind”);
      exit (1);
    }

signal(SIGINT, sig_term);

while ((recv = recvfrom (sockfd, (void *) &alert, sizeof (alert),
                   0, (struct sockaddr *) &bogus, &len)) > 0)
    {

/* do validation of recv if you care */

  if (!(alert.val & NOPACKET_STRUCT))
    {
      if ((p = calloc (1, sizeof (Packet))) == NULL)
        {
          perror ("calloc");
          exit (1);
        }

      p->pkt = alert.pkt;
      p->pkth = &alert.pkth;
      if (alert.dlthdr)
        p->eh = (EtherHdr *) (alert.pkt + alert.dlthdr);
      if (alert.nethdr)
        {
          p->iph = (IPHdr *) (alert.pkt + alert.nethdr);
          if (alert.transhdr)
            {
              switch (p->iph->ip_proto)
                {
                case IPPROTO_TCP:
                  p->tcph = (TCPHdr *) (alert.pkt + alert.transhdr);
                  break;
                case IPPROTO_UDP:
                  p->udph = (UDPHdr *) (alert.pkt + alert.transhdr);
                  break;
                case IPPROTO_ICMP:
                  p->icmph = (ICMPHdr *) (alert.pkt + alert.transhdr);
                  break;
                default:
              printf ("My, that's interesting.\n");
                }                /* case */
            }                /* thanshdr */
        }                        /* nethdr */
      if (alert.data)
        p->data = alert.pkt + alert.data;

      /*  now  do whatever you want with these packet structures */
    }                        /* if (!NOPACKET_STRUCT) */

  printf ("%s [%d]\n", alert.alertmsg, alert.event.event_id);
  if (!(alert.val & NOPACKET_STRUCT))
    if (p->iph && (p->tcph || p->udph || p->icmph))
      {
        switch (p->iph->ip_proto)
          {
          case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf ("TCP from: %s:%d ",
                    inet_ntoa (p->iph->ip_src),
                    ntohs (p->tcph->th_sport));
            printf ("to: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa (p->iph->ip_dst),
                    ntohs (p->tcph->th_dport));
            break;
          case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf ("UDP from: %s:%d ",
                    inet_ntoa (p->iph->ip_src),
                    ntohs (p->udph->uh_sport));
            printf ("to: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa (p->iph->ip_dst),
                    ntohs (p->udph->uh_dport));
            break;
          case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf ("ICMP type: %d code: %d from: %s ",
                    p->icmph->type,
                    p->icmph->code, inet_ntoa (p->iph->ip_src));
            printf ("to: %s\n", inet_ntoa (p->iph->ip_dst));
            break;
          }
      }

}


perror (“recvfrom”);
  close (sockfd);
  unlink (UNSOCK_FILE);

return 0;
}
```